# How to speed up task<t> with httpclient

Tags: c#, optimization, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

I have a processes where I need to make ~100 http api calls to a server and process the results. I've put together this commandexecutor which builds a list of commands and then runs them async. To make about 100 calls and parse the result is taking over 1 minute. 1 request using a browser give me a response in ~100ms. You would think that ~100 calls would be around 10 seconds. I believe that I am doing something wrong and that this should go much faster.

```
 public static class CommandExecutor
 {
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<List<Command>> CommandsToExecute =
        new ThreadLocal<List<Command>>(() => new List<Command>());
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<List<Task<List<Candidate>>>> Tasks =
        new ThreadLocal<List<Task<List<Candidate>>>>(() => new List<Task<List<Candidate>>>());

    public static void ExecuteLater(Command command)
    {
        CommandsToExecute.Value.Add(command);
    }

    public static void StartExecuting()
    {
        foreach (var command in CommandsToExecute.Value)
        {
            Tasks.Value.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Candidate>>(command.GetResult));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(Tasks.Value.ToArray());
    }

    public static List<Candidate> Result()
    {
        return Tasks.Value.Where(x => x.Result != null)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.Result)
                          .ToList();
    }
}
```

The Command that I am passing into this list creates a new httpclient, calls the getasync on that client with a url, converts the string response to an object then hydrates a field.

```
    protected void Initialize()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    protected override void Execute()
    {
        Initialize();

        var task = _httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format(Url, Input));
        Result = ConvertResponseToObjectAsync(task).Result;
        Result.ForEach(x => x.prop = value);
    }

    private static Task<Model> ConvertResponseToObjectAsync(Task<HttpResponseMessage> task)
    {
        return task.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model>(
           new MediaTypeFormatter[]
           {
                 new Formatter()
           });
    }
```

Can you pick up on my bottleneck or have any suggestions on how to speed this up.

**EDIT**
making these changes made it down to 4 seconds.

```
protected override void Execute()
    {
        Initialize();

        _httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format(Url, Input))
        .ContinueWith(httpResponse => ConvertResponseToObjectAsync(httpResponse)
        .ContinueWith(ProcessResult));
    }

    protected void ProcessResult(Task<Model> model)
    {
        Result = model.Result;
        Result.ForEach(x => x.prop = value);
    }
```

Comment: Did you make any measurements? How fast does each request execute? Where is most of the time spent? Are all of the requests to the same server?

Comment: Also check how many parallel requests you actually able to make. There are some default restrictions that may limit throughput.

Comment: dotTrace (i'm new to it) says that 63% is on  system.threading.monitor.wait. I will add some debug print statements to see how fast each one is executing. I've already made some changes to the code, i will update the question to reflect if it doesn't help.

Comment: You block on tasks finishing instead of doing ContinueWith (or using async/await), both in ConvertResponseToObjectAsync (which will block until the input task completes) and Execute, which will block when the returned Task is completed.  You'd normally 'await' them instead, or if you can't use await, then ContinueWith so you're not blocking waiting on the Task to complete.

Comment: thanks @JamesManning I fixed it in one of those spots. Can you comment on the edit I added?

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not clear on why you'd use ThreadLocal when dealing with tasks - tasks can aren't normally thread-affine, so I would think collections of tasks would just be a 'singleton' instead of per-thread.  Does more than a single thread call StartExecuting?

Comment: @JamesManning no, i'm pretty sure I misunderstood its usage and will look for a replacement.

Comment: wow i'm down to 750 milliseconds now...

Comment: since you're calling ConvertResponseToObjectAsync in a ContinueWith now, it could pass the Result (so the method parameter would be HttpResponseMessage instead of Task<HttpResponseMessage>) to help make it clear that it's not getting called on a task that's still running.  Similarly, I'd have ProcessResult accept just Model.

Comment: @JamesManning so calling .Result in a continueWith won't block? it doesn't seem to and it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @Steve - correct, since you're in a ContinueWith, it's only calling it when the task has completed.  If it completed with a failure, then accessing the Result will throw the AggregateException containing the error(s) from the task.

Comment: @Steve - not really related to this, but in case it's an option, you can use async/await with .NET 4.0 and Silverlight 5 with VS2012 and the Async Targeting Pack.  IMHO, it makes for easier to read/understand code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the use of `task.Result` in ConvertResponseToObjectAsync and then again in `Execute`.  Instead chain these on to the original `GetAsync` task with `ContinueWith`.

As it stands today, `Result` will block execution of the current thread until the other task finishes.  However, your threadpool will quickly get backed up by tasks waiting on other tasks that have nowhere to run.  Eventually (after waiting for a second), the threadpool will add an additional thread to run and so this will eventually finish, but it's hardly efficient.

As a general principle, you should avoid ever accessing `Task.Result` except in a task continuation.

As a bonus, you probably don't want to be using `ThreadLocalStorage`.  `ThreadLocalStorage` stores an instance of the item stored in it *on each thread* where it is accessed.  In this case, it looks like you want a thread-safe but shared form of storage.  I would recommend `ConcurrentQueue` for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

Stop creating new HttpClient instances.  Everytime you dispose a HttpClient instance it closes the TCP/IP connection.  Create one HttpClient instance and re-use it for every request.  HttpClient can make multiple requests on multiple different threads at the same time.