# c# - Optimizing parallel HttpClient requests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, optimization, httprequest, httpclient

I need to go through a string array and simulate HttpRequests for each element of the array and process the response but this takes negligible time compared to the request times. This is how I realised it:

**Request method (is contained in a class which has a shared HttpClient instance):**

```
private async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(string link)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/" + link + "/orders"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));
        request.Headers.Referrer = new Uri("https://warframe.market/items/" + link);
        return await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
```

**The method which sends the request, decompresses it and analyzes it:**

```
    public async Task<int> GetLowestPriceForItem(string itemName)
    {
        try
        {
            var responseMessage = await GetResponseMessage(itemName);
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                byte[] byteResponse = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                byte[] decompress = BrotliDecompress(byteResponse);  //negligble time       
                string text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decompress);
                WarframeMarketDeserializer deserializer = new WarframeMarketDeserializer(text);
                return deserializer.GetLowestSellPrice(); //negligble
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("The price for the item wasn't properly fetched. Error message: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**The method through which requests are called for all the elements in an array:**

```
    public async void HandleHotkey()
    {//Handles the hotkey (and does necessary checks)

        if (ForegroundWindow.IsInFocus(targetProcess.MainWindowHandle) && !KeyPressed)  //should be IsFullscreen, this is for testing
        {
            KeyPressed = true;

            string[] items = { "tigris_prime_stock", "tigris_prime_receiver", "tigris_prime_barrel", "tigris_prime_blueprint" };
            int[] itemPrices = new int[items.Length];
            WarframeMarketClient client = new WarframeMarketClient();
            var tasks = items.Select(async item =>
            {
                itemPrices[Array.IndexOf(items, item)] = await client.GetLowestPriceForItem(item);
            });
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                result = result + items[i] + " " + itemPrices[i].ToString() + "\n ";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(result);
            KeyPressed = false;
        }
    }
```

The method which sends requests takes the most time, around 600ms per instance (when I analyze the requests through a browser, exactly same web requests take around 200-300ms to "get"), when I run them parallel, all 4 requests are sent and processed in 1.9s

I looked around StackOverflow and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236844/how-to-speed-up-taskt-with-httpclient) and tried to implement some ideas from it. Namely linking async methods through *ContinueWith*. Now the method which sends the request looked like this:

```
    public async Task<int> GetLowestPriceForItem(string itemName)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> getMessageTask = GetResponseMessage(itemName);
            Task<int> getPrice = await getMessageTask.ContinueWith(i => HandleResponseMessage(i.Result));
            return await getPrice;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("The price for the item wasn't properly fetched. Error message: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<int> HandleResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        int itemPrice = 0;
        if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Task<byte[]> byteDecompressed = message.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ContinueWith(i => BrotliDecompress(i.Result));
            Task<string> stringDecompressed = byteDecompressed.ContinueWith(i => 
            {
                return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(i.Result);
            });
            Task itemPriceResult = stringDecompressed.ContinueWith(i =>
            {
                WarframeMarketDeserializer deserializer = new WarframeMarketDeserializer(stringDecompressed.Result);
                itemPrice = deserializer.GetLowestSellPrice();
            });
            await itemPriceResult;
            return itemPrice;             
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Response from the site (warframe.market) was invalid.");
        }           
    }
```

But, the time taken was still the same. Roughly 1.9s for 4 items. Is it possible to speed this up and how?

Thank you for reading

Comment: You *don't* need to use `ContinueWith` when using `async/await`. You don't need to decompress anything, HttpClient does that already. You *shouldn't* decode to ASCII, HttpClient checks the actual content type and decodes the content properly if required.

Comment: If you want to request four urls in parallel, just write `var tasks=myUrlArray.Select(url=>client.GetStringAsync(url)); var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: That's a lot of code so apologies if I'm missing something, but this is **definitely not** something you want to do on a shared `HttpClient` because it is not thread safe: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add`

Comment: If the response is JSON, you can deserialize it to matching objects directly with essentially the same code `var tasks=myUrlArray.Select(async url=>{ var response=client.GetAsync(url); return await response.Content.ReasAsAsync<MyObject>()}); var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: @Crowcoder on the contrary, HttpClient **is** thread safe and you *shouldn't* create new instances for each new call. HttpClient preserves OS socket so it's a lot more scaleable to use the same instance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but not the DefaultRequestHeaders. If the headers must vary per use you set them on an `HttpRequestMessage` and then `SendAsync()`

Comment: @Crowcoder this has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it certainly does. You can introduce a race condition.

Comment: @Crowcoder in any case, *none* of this code is needed once the OP uses HttpClient properly.

Comment: @Crowcoder no race condition, although an error is probable. The only header added to `DefaultRequestHeaders` is an identical `user-agent`. Everything else is added to the request

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos HttpClient certainly wasn't decoding it on its own, but I updated the library now and we'll see if that changes. I'll try out the ReadAsAsync<> too.

Comment: @DjordjeNikolic regardless of arguments to the contrary, `DefaultRequestHeaders` is not thread safe so next time you use it be aware of it. Setting it once is fine, but you appear to be setting it on every call and that just piles up the same header value in the header collection. So either set it once in the shared instance or be sure to `Clear()` it first.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I implemented it the way you told me to:`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://warframe.market/");
                var tasks = items.Select(async item =>
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/" + item + "/orders");
                    var nesto = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
                    itemPrices[Array.IndexOf(items, item)] = GetLowestSellPrice(nesto);
                });
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the difference in execution time is really really small, like, for the whole array maybe just half a tenth or sometimes even less.

Comment: @Crowcoder I didn't know that they pile up, will fix that. Tnx

Comment: @DjordjeNikolic can you share the final snippet - i dont explicitly use default headers. m clearing them up but dont see change. using RestSharp client though

Comment: @singhsumit Sorry for answering late, I haven't checked SO for a while. In the end, what I ended up using was very simple, and you can take a look [here](https://github.com/Djordje-Nikolic/WarframeMarketOverlay/blob/master/WarframeMarketOverlay/WarframeQueryHandler.cs). HttpClient initialization is done in the method Execute, and I send requests and receive the response in the method HandleResult.